# OOTB Workflow issue in approving?

Tags: workflow, outlook, out-of-the-box

Precisely and concisely, My client has set an OOTB workflow on a document library and one of the users e.g. (User1) is unable to approve documents even though I granted that particular user (User1) **Full Control** and put the account inside the "**Approvers**" user group.

Currently, The user is getting an email in the Outlook stating: **Task update was not accepted**.

Also, I would like to mention that there has been no any changes for the user's account in the AD.

So, Could you please help me out to resolve this issue ?

I would greatly appreciate your inputs !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this article will be able to solve your issue:
[Approval Workflow Knowledge](http://stevepietrek.com/2008/05/02/approval-workflow-knowledge/)

From the above article:

> The second page of the approval workflow association form “Allow
>   changes to the participant list when this workflow is started”. By
>   default, this option is checked. If this is checked, the workflow
>   initiator can make changes. To avoid this issue, uncheck this option.
>   Unchecking this option will rollback any changes the workflow
>   initiator has made and display the message: “Task update was not
>   accepted”. All in all, I guess it makes sense. If the workflow
>   initiator can assign to someone else, it also means they can make
>   changes herself.

If even that doesn't work for you... I will recommend you to re-check the role **"FULL CONTROL"** is itself not edited and approval permissions are missing from the Full Control...

I hope this helps